# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

This is my program  :(

```
private void btnPhone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[,] numbers = new string[5, 1];

    numbers[0, 0] = "Pedro";
    numbers[0, 1] = "4633585";

    numbers[1, 0] = "Juan";
    numbers[1, 1] = "6364799";

    numbers[2, 0] = "Pepe";
    numbers[2, 1] = "7172572";

    numbers[3, 0] = "Lucia";
    numbers[3, 1] = "8885200";

    numbers[4, 0] = "Marta";
    numbers[4, 1] = "7171700";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i, 0] == txtName.Text)
        {
            txtNumber.Text = numbers[i, 1];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is hardly a question and even less stackoverflow question.

Comment: @VDohnal - why isn't it?

Comment: @DeeMac I see only text `This is my program :(` which is gramatically a statement, not a question. I believe it should be migrated to the Codereview site.

Comment: @VDohnal - I don't think this meets the requirements for code review (must have working program) and I also don't think its a question since it is just a code dump. It should just be closed as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `new string[5, 2]`. And also in the loop it should be `i<5` instead of `i<=5`.

Comment: Right, also there is off by one error. If you add that also I'd upvote..

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (numbers[i, 0] == txtName.Text)
    {
       txtNumber.Text = numbers[i, 1];
    }
}
```

At least this way you're not explicitly declaring how many iterations the for loop should complete. Play it safe to avoid scenarios like this (you may want to add another or remove an element in the future). The way you're doing it at the moment is bad practice, if not only for the messing around you'll have to do to keep the array size and for loop in sync through any changes made.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `numbers[5, i]`, as arrays in c# are zero-aligned so when you try to access it, it's out of range. Try using

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second dimension of the array is just one element,, but you try to access two.

```
numbers = new string[5, 1];

numbers[0, 0] = "Pedro";
numbers[0, 1] = "4633585";
```

Try

```
numbers = new string[5, 2];
```

instead.